# Customize comment list markup

Tags: theme-development, walker, comments

While creating a new theme, we'll have to customize the comment flow. For doing so there are two functions: `wp_list_comments()` and `get_comments()`. I am not very sure how to style the inner elements that appear from it such as Gravatar, comment description, comment author, etc. In order to do some styling for them, I first of all need to know the DOM elements assigned to them. Where can I go to find about them?

I've tried in almost all the sources, I am unable to understand properly.

Comment: Try using the Firebug add-on in Firefox, or the Developers Tools (F12) in Google Chrome

Answer (score 4):

You should use `wp_list_comments()`, because this will call a Walker class that can handle comment threads:

```
// from wp_list_comments()
if ( empty($walker) )
    $walker = new Walker_Comment;

$walker->paged_walk($_comments, $max_depth, $page, $per_page, $r);
```

`Walker_Comment` handles the markup for the comments. You can pass a custom walker to change it.

Example:

```
class Simple_Comment_Walker extends Walker_Comment
{
    function start_el( &$output, $comment, $depth, $args, $id = 0 ) {
        $depth++;
        $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth;
        $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;

        print '<li>' . get_comment_author_link() . '<br>';
        comment_text();
    }
}

wp_list_comments( array ( 'walker' => new Simple_Comment_Walker ) );
```

But this is not needed if you want to change the single comment markup only. You can pass a `callback` parameter to `wp_list_comments()` to do the same:

```
function simple_callback() 
{
    print '<li>' . get_comment_author_link() . '<br>';
    comment_text();
}
wp_list_comments( array ( 'callback' => 'simple_callback' ) );
```

- Use a custom walker if you want to change the container elements for the comment list too, use a callback if you want to change single comments only.
- You can overwrite everything in `Walker_Comment`, see `wp-includes/comment-template.php` for details.
- Keep in mind you should **not close** the first comment container (in my examples the `<li>`), the Walker does this when the whole thread has been printed.