# Repositioning 'Reply' Link in Comments

Tags: comments

I'm calling my comments the ol' fashion way:

```
<?php wp_list_comments('avatar_size=60'); ?>
```

I would like to be able to position the 'Reply" link where I choose.  Right now, it defaults to the bottom of the comment.  Sure, I can move it via CSS - but what if I want to place it after the dater or username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [custom callback](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77188/customize-comment-list-markup/77189#77189) to render the comment content. Inside of the callback function call `comment_reply_link()` wherever you need it:

```
comment_reply_link(
    array_merge(
        $args,
        array (
            'add_below' => 'comment-body',
            'depth'     => $reply_depth,
            // + 1 to offer always a reply link for a consistent UI
            'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] + 1,
            'before'    => '<p class="reply-line">',
            'after'     => '</p>'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi, toscho with this array of add_below of comment-body i can move the div reply to top? before the footer?

i means i want to show the comment-reply-link in top...

Comment: @ccdiego5 Sure just use a custom [comment callback](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77189/73) and place the div wherever you need it.